# Apt behind proxy

Tags: apt, proxy, authentication

I've been trying to get a package manager to work behind our company proxy for a whole day now but without any luck. The proxy requires authentication which is my personal email address and password. I tried just about everything I could think of with no luck: From editing `/etc/apt/apt.conf` with `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:pass@proxy:port/";` using simply my username, I tried escaping the "@" but no luck. Browser works fine but I don't really need a browser. The system administrator wished me good luck and that pretty much sums up his assistance. So If anyone can help I would really really really appreciate it.

Comment: Try using %40 instead of @ in your mailaddress.

Comment: Nope. I still get 407 Proxy Authentication Required. Which is right where I started.

Comment: Are you using apt-get or a gui tool? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987292/apt-get-behind-a-proxy-with-authentication seems to indicate that apt-get should work with this (though he has the @ sign in the password). A 407 seems to indicate it doesn't see use a password at all instead of merely the wrong one. Are you still setting it in apt.conf?

Comment: apt-get. I have never used the gui tools. Or ubuntu for that matter as I am an rpm type of man. That doesn't really matter though. And yes-I put all that into apt.conf.

Comment: It might help if you explain what the exact errors are you are getting with the config, and include an example or two in the question.

Comment: `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy:port/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://user:password@proxy:port/";`

`W: Failed to fetch http:://us.archive.ubuntu.com/.../Packages` 407 Proxy Authentication Required`

That's pretty much all.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/424542/251032

PS: I know this is a pretty old question, but since it took me a couple of years to figure out the details of how to use apt with a proxy, it's possible that an answer is still welcome.